# One Facebook Account for App and Page, How?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Today I need to create a new facebook app, since I need the app_id for the social plugins. 
I created a facebook "page" account for my product's website before, but I found that I can't create a new app by using the "page" account:

Create Facebook App: 
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

I have to login with normal user account in order to create a new app, so I am very confused now... Should I re-create a new user account and then create a facebook app? But what to do with my existing "page" account then?

I just want to bind everything together, hopefully one facebook account to bind the "app" and the "page".

By the way, do users know who (account) created that App?

Thanks!!

Comment: Nope - you can't.  Have to use a real user account to create applications.  [I gave an answer talking about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9738891/558021) perhaps it'll help for now.  Good luck!

Comment: I don't think that you can tell who opened the account.   But there is a "contact developer" link when you are viewing an application and you click the "report" button - http://i.imgur.com/IqKFx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a Facebook application as a Facebook page. You cannot access any other application as a Facebook page. If you try to open an application when you're acting as a FB page, you'll be ask to switch back to your regular account.

A page identity is not an account. You cannot even login to FB as a page, you must login with your user account and then switch to page mode. It's only an identity you can use to comment or post. They only introduced recently the messaging system for pages and it's still very buggy.

You don't need a new account. You can use the same account you used to create the FB page to create the FB app. Everything will be bound to your normal user account.

**EDIT**

Since you add a question to your post: you can create the application and use your user account as owner. Or you can create the app using a company name, so your user account will not be listed in the application.

Comment: Sometimes people don't want their work sliding into their personal life.  Your Facebook account is a personal thing and I might not want an application I'm working on (for my job) to be publicly associated with my personal Facebook account.

Comment: @Lix I understand your issue and I have a fake FB account myself. But the OP stated that he already created a page using his account, so I didn't consider this as an issue in my answer.

Comment: I created the page by a new account, and it is just a page account, not the same as normal user account. This page account can't be used to create app after login. So I think I should open a new business user account to create the app...

Comment: Should I create a new app or page first?

Comment: @RRN Create a new business user. Add your new account as an admin to the page you already created, then create the application with your business user.

Comment: How can I add the new business user as the admin of the existing page??

Comment: @RRN Go to 'Admin Roles' in the page settings, and your business account.

Comment: this is not work, when I tried to add admin role, it said you can only add your friend or something, end up I need to create new account and new page, it seems working for sure.

Comment: @RRN You must add your business account as a friend ;) At least you got it working.