# Facebook Login without a Facebook Account nor through a third-party app

Tags: facebook, authentication, plugins

Does anyone know of a way to use social logins without having to create an account with a social media website? For Example, I want to use Facebook's Login on my website, but I do not want to create a Facebook account nor an app just to use their login.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know it pretty much requires (facebook) an App to be created (on developer site for facebook) in order to utilized services with a website.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in order to maintain a safe development environment, and to prevent the creation of spam apps, it is required that Facebook manage its developer users. This is to allow them to block apps that act maliciously, and to allow permissions to be managed on their server for the app access token. For a more detailed answer, I'll refer you to [one on StackOverflow by Lix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738831/developing-for-the-facebook-api-without-getting-a-facebook-account).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I kind of already knew the answer, but I wanted to make sure because there were no straight answers on Facebook's or other social medias' website. And using a search engine for the answer didn't get me anything either.